# Canvas controls video without child attribute errors

Tags: javascript, python, html, video, canvas

Say i want to draw controls in canvas video without using video as parent attribute.With this code i am able to control canvas with video but somehow i want canvas without video as parent just simply controls canvas.Is it possible in any language?Or may be stupid question but pls help.
Code i am using but don't want to use:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Load Video Onto The Canvas</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var videoElement;
var videoDiv;
function eventWindowLoaded() {
videoElement = document.createElement("video");
videoDiv = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(videoDiv);
videoDiv.appendChild(videoElement);
}
function videoLoaded(event) {
canvasApp();
}
function canvasApp() {
context.fillStyle = '#ffffaa';
context.fillRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
//Box
context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
context.strokeRect(5, 5, theCanvas.width-10, theCanvas.height-10);
//video
context.drawImage(videoElement , 85, 30);
}
var theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
setInterval(drawScreen, 33);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<video id="video" width="320" height="240">
<source src="video/browser.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' >
<source src="video/browser.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;">
<canvas id="canvasOne" width="500" height="300">
Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: you want to draw only the video players controls (play, stop, pause etc.) to the canvas, not the video itself?

This can't be done. We have no access to the controls as these are supplied internally by the browser.

The only way around this is to disable the controls in the video element and manually create buttons using normal DOM elements, or by drawing and implement logic for them with the canvas (if you want the artistic freedom).

These buttons that you create manually, whether DOM/HTML buttons or canvas, simply triggers the commands on the video element itself from code (ie. `play()` etc.).

**[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/HVmm4/)** I made a while back (although for a different purpose).

Comment: Ok,i understand.But just give answer,suppose i have video drawing on canvas and i want to play video and pause on mouseenter & mouseout in canvas,is it possible in anyway?

Comment: @Ranidubey certainly, just attach an event handler for the canvas element and invoke the proper command on the video element to start/stop etc. depending on the event. For example: `theCanvas.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {videoElement.play();}, false);` and stop for mouse leave/out etc. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh dear,thank you.You saved me a lot of hurdle.I get a clue how to merge above problem with this.